# How can I install nvm in windows?

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have tired installing nvm with cURL command:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
```

I have installed nvm but I couldn't use nvm command:

```
$ nvm --version
bash: nvm: command not found
```

if I try to update nvm I get this,

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13527  100 13527    0     0  15441      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15441
=> nvm is already installed in /c/Users/VIJAY R/.nvm, trying to update using git
=> error: invalid path 'test/fast/Aliases/"nvm alias" should not accept aliases with slashes'
=> Compressing and cleaning up git repository

=> nvm source string already in /c/Users/VIJAY R/.bash_profile
=> bash_completion source string already in /c/Users/VIJAY R/.bash_profile
main: line 397: /c/Users/VIJAY R/.nvm/nvm.sh: No such file or directory
npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2        
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2      
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2       
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: cli-width@^2.0.0, required by inquirer@7.0.0
npm ERR! missing: emoji-regex@^8.0.0, required by string-width@4.1.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: @babel/code-frame@^7.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-scope@^5.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: espree@^6.1.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esquery@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: functional-red-black-tree@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: ignore@^4.0.6, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: import-fresh@^3.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: imurmurhash@^0.1.4, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: json-stable-stringify-without-jsonify@^1.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: levn@^0.3.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: natural-compare@^1.4.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: progress@^2.0.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: regexpp@^2.0.1, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: table@^5.2.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: text-table@^0.2.0, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: v8-compile-cache@^2.0.3, required by eslint@6.7.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-deep-equal@^2.0.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: fast-json-stable-stringify@^2.0.0, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: json-schema-traverse@^0.4.1, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: uri-js@^4.2.2, required by ajv@6.10.2
npm ERR! missing: esutils@^2.0.2, required by doctrine@3.0.0
npm ERR! missing: eslint-visitor-keys@^1.1.0, required by eslint-utils@1.4.3
npm ERR! missing: mimic-fn@^2.1.0, required by onetime@5.1.0
npm ERR! missing: emoji-regex@^8.0.0, required by string-width@4.1.0
npm ERR! missing: flatted@^2.0.0, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: rimraf@2.6.3, required by flat-cache@2.0.1
npm ERR! missing: type-fest@^0.8.1, required by globals@12.3.0
npm ERR! missing: deep-is@~0.1.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: levn@~0.3.0, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: prelude-ls@~1.1.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: type-check@~0.3.2, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: word-wrap@~1.2.3, required by optionator@0.8.3
npm ERR! missing: chai@^4.1.2, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: deep-equal@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: json-stringify-safe@^5.0.1, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: propagate@^1.0.0, required by nock@9.6.1
npm ERR! missing: qs@^6.5.1, required by nock@9.6.1
=> You currently have modules installed globally with `npm`. These will no
=> longer be linked to the active version of Node when you install a new node
=> with `nvm`; and they may (depending on how you construct your `$PATH`)
=> override the binaries of modules installed with `nvm`:

C:\Users\VIJAY R\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @angular/cli@10.1.6
+-- heroku@7.46.0
`-- nodemon@2.0.4
=> If you wish to uninstall them at a later point (or re-install them under your
=> `nvm` Nodes), you can remove them from the system Node as follows:

     $ nvm use system
     $ npm uninstall -g a_module

=> Close and reopen your terminal to start using nvm or run the following to use it now:

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [important notes section of the nvm doc](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#important-notes):

> Note: nvm does not support Windows (see [#284](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/284)), but may work in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) depending on the version of WSL. For Windows, two alternatives exist, which are neither supported nor developed by us:
>
> - nvm-windows
> - nodist

You may have better luck trying [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) or [nodist](https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [nvs](https://nodejs.dev/en/). Install it via the [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) package manager.

Comment: The other option is fnm.